# Unable to write to script element using JavaScript in IE 5 quirks mode

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, quirks-mode

I have an application that works on IE browser only. I have an issue with the application running on IE10 with IE 5 quirks document mode.

I am trying to write some JavaScript, that I receive from my server, into the page using JavaScript, but I found that when the page is in IE 5 quirks mode, an error is thrown by the browser. However, when I attempt to do the same in Quirks mode, the script works fine.

I cannot switch to quirks mode, because the application is not-usable (the entire page is not viewable, controls inaccessible) in Quirks or standards mode.

Following is the script that I am trying to get executed:

```
var scr = document.createElement('script');
scr.type = 'text/javascript';
scr.innerText = 'function Test123(){alert("123");}'; //this is the line that throws the exception
document.body.appendChild(scr);
```

Could anyone please let me know how to get the above script executed in IE 5 quirks mode?

Comment: Have you tried setting the *text* property instead? Also try putting the script an external file and set the *src* property. IE 5 is pretty ancient, why do you need to support it?

Comment: I don't need to support IE 5. Unfortunately I have inherited code that generates html visible only in IE5 quirks mode. I cannot put the script in an external file since a functions with distinct names are generated during the course of the code execution and they are embedded into the page. I cannot extract that code because that would require a lot of work and I am very much short of time.

Comment: I don't think IE supports textContext. textContext is supported in mozilla

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved by setting the text property instead of the innerText property.